# Push your luck type scenario

Tags: probability, expected-value

I had the following problem on a handout about EV (expected value).

> Consider the following game: you have a coin and a score, initially $0$. The following two events each occur with probability $\frac{1}{2}$:
>
> - Your score increases by $1$.
> - Your score is set to $0$, and the round ends.
>
> You are allowed to play at most $r$ rounds. At any point, you may end the game immediately, and your final score will be equal to the current score. However, if the $r$-th round has ended, your final score is $0$.
>
> Find the maximum value of the expected final score you can have, when (a) $r = 1$ and (b) $r=3$.

**I have solved the $r=1$ case as follows:**

Suppose you decide to stop after $k$ events. The probability the round hasn't ended yet is $\frac{1}{2^k}$, and your score in this case is $k$. Therefore, the answer in this case will just be $\max_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{k}{2^k}\right)$, which is $\frac{1}{2}$ (at $k=1$ and $k=2$). However, I am having trouble applying this to the $r=3$ case. It seems like I have to use linearity of expectation somehow, but I don't see how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that if you play two complete rounds in the $r=3$ case your score is reset to $0$ and you are playing a one round game.  You have shown that the expectation of a one round game is $\frac 12$.  If you are playing $r=3$ and have already finished one round your score starts at $0$, but if it resets you expect $\frac 12$.  Your expectation if you will play $k_2$ tries in the second round is then $\frac {k_2}{2^{k_2}}+\frac{2^{k_2}-1}{2^{k_2}}\cdot\frac 12$ where the first term comes from not failing in the second round and the last term comes from if you fail in the second round.  Maximize this over $k_2$ to find the value at $r=2$.  Then do the same with the maximum as the expected value if you fail on the first round.  You will find the value $k_1$ of the number of tries you should do on the first round before quitting, then find the value of the game.